# Error installing Perl Module. Error code 129

Tags: perl, module, installation, cmd

Thank you for taking the time reading this and hopefully help me come out with a successful solution to my problem.

I deleted this previous post as it went dead(hours without an answer), so Im hoping to revive it.

I was trying to install a perl module  named Rose::DB, and after multiple approaches I finally installed it, but whenever I run my code it tells me it can't find a module named Bit::Vector, so I tried to install it.

I first did the Makefile.PL without errors.
Then, I tried doing the dmake... and It gave me A LOT of lines, most of them warnings like this:

```
Vector.o:Vector.c:(.text+0x11591): undefined reference to `_imp__Perl_newXS'
Vector.o:Vector.c:(.text+0x115a0): undefined reference to `_imp__Perl_get_context'
```

After that the last couple of lines showed this:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\Bit\Vector\Vector.dll'
```

Can anybody help me install the module correctly? I would really appreciate it.

PS: Here's the link to see all the lines:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/97pk32

PS: I'm using Strawberry, was using ActivePerl but gave me errors and was recommended to use Strawberry.

Comment: Fools giving advice, it is abhorrent. [ActivePerl does have a working Bit-Vector PPM package](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Bit-Vector/), no compilation required.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I first tried installing the module on ActivePerl, but it gave me errors of not finding other modules(that Strawberry could install), what would be the process to install the module correctly? I'm sorry to ask, but I'm pretty ignorant in this matter... and is it viewed as wrong to ask the same question twice?(After deleting the previous one, in order to revive the subject due to lack of response)

Comment: See http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl about your first question. – Your other question about whether asking twice is essentially about how this site works. Go discuss topics like that at http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you...I will try to install it with ppm(I already tried the rest). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on **Windows** with the module Win32::UTCFileTime.

It can be due to the fact that you have both Strawberry and ActivePerl installed. And so, your perl configuration may be wrong.

If you have something like :

```
$ perl -V
...
cc='C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gcc.exe',...
...
ld='C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\g++.exe', ldflags='... -L"C:\Perl\lib\CORE"...'
...
```

It means that you are trying to build perl modules with Strawberry's compiler/linker and with ActivePerl libs. It could be the reason why.

Also, an easy "hack" is to **rename C:\Perl to C:\whatever** temporarily.
Then, you should have :

```
$ perl -V
...
cc='gcc',...
...
ld='g++', ldflags='... -L"C:\strawberry\lib\CORE"...'
...
```

Thus, your linker will be able to find Strawberry perl CORE API functions ( _imp__Perl_*, [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) ). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two perl installation like Strawbery and other like Dwimperl or activeperl, renaming one which is not used, solved my problem of dmake.exe:  Error code 129